# Sum of values of json array in PostgreSQL

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

In PostgreSQL 9.3, I have a table like this

```
id | array_json
---+----------------------------
1  | ["{123: 456}", "{789: 987}", "{111: 222}"]
2  | ["{4322: 54662}", "{123: 5121}", "{1: 5345}" ... ]
3  | ["{3232: 413}", "{5235: 22}", "{2: 5453}" ... ]
4  | ["{22: 44}", "{12: 4324}", "{234: 4235}" ... ]
...
```

I want to get **the sum of all values in array_json column**. So, for example, for first row, I want:

```
id | total
---+-------
1  | 1665
```

Where **1665 = 456 + 987 + 222** (the values of all the elements of json array). No previous information about the keys of the json elements (just random numbers)

I'm reading the documentation page about [JSON functions in PostgreSQL 9.3](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html), and I think I should use **json_each**, but can't find the right query. Could you please help me with it?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You started looking at the right place (going to the docs is always the right place).**

Since your values are JSON arrays -> I would suggest using `json_array_elements(json)`

And since it's a json array which you have to explode to several rows, and then combine back by running sum over `json_each_text(json)` - it would be best to create your own function (Postgres allows it)

As for your specific case, assuming the structure you provided is correct, some string parsing + JSON heavy wizardry can be used (let's say your table name is "json_test_table" and the columns are "id" and "json_array"), here is the query that does your "thing"

```
select id, sum(val) from 
    (select id,
     substring(
        json_each_text(
          replace(
           replace(
            replace(
             replace(
              replace(json_array,':','":"')
             ,'{',''),
            '}','')
           ,']','}')
          ,'[','{')::json)::varchar 
     from '\"(.*)\"')::int  as val  
   from json_test_table) j group by id ;
```

if you plan to run it on a huge dataset - keep in mind string manipulations are expensive in terms of performance

Comment: Great! I've found a solution, but using intermediate tables and/or with clauses. This is more elegant. Many thanks!

Comment: @jorgeas80 Look to my answer, perhaps you can find it more elegant too :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using this:

```
/*
Sorry, sqlfiddle is busy :p
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  array_json json[]
  --,CONSTRAINT my_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

INSERT INTO my_table(array_json)
   values (array['{"123": 456}'::json, '{"789": 987}'::json, '{"111": 222}'::json]);
*/   

select id, sum(json_value::integer)
from
(
select id, json_data->>json_object_keys(json_data) as json_value from
    (
    select id,  unnest(array_json) as json_data from my_table
    ) A
) B 
group by id
```